# Compiler optimization creating a syscall?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, compiler-construction, cross-compiling

I am compiling a fairly sophisticated application in two modes: Debug and Release. The main difference, as I see it, is -O0 vs -O3 (I can provide the relevant part of makefile if needed). I am trying to avoid syscall generation as much as possible, as I am simulating this application in syscall emulation mode (no OS running underneath). The problem that i am currently having is that in Release mode the compiler generates an extra socket syscall, which I prefer not to happen (and which does not happen in Debug mode).

The reason that I think the socket might be created is that I am using pthreads and two of my threads are communicating through a volatile char*. So I'm guessing maybe the compiler is trying to implement it in a fancy way when I set the -O3 flag? But I'm not sure if that is a reasonable assumption.

1. Is it possible that the socket syscall is being generated because of the -O3 flag? (doesn't make too much sense)
2. If so, how can I hint to the compiler to avoid generating this syscall?

EDIT: BTW the code is in C and C++

EDIT: The code is statically linked against the following shared libraries:

```
libstdc++.a 
libm.a 
libglib-2.0.a 
-static-libgcc 
*special pthreads library*
```

Also, I found where in the binary the call to socket is happening:

```
8c716:       db28            blt.n   8c76a <openlog_internal+0xf2>
8c718:       f8d9 1008       ldr.w   r1, [r9, #8]
8c71c:       4620            mov     r0, r4
8c71e:       2200            movs    r2, #0
8c720:       f441 2100       orr.w   r1, r1, #524288 ; 0x80000
8c724:       f001 e97c       blx     8da20 <__socket>
8c728:       4b20            ldr     r3, [pc, #128]  ; (8c7ac <openlog_internal+0x134>)
8c72a:       681b            ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
8c72c:       f8c9 0004       str.w   r0, [r9, #4]
8c730:       b943            cbnz    r3, 8c744 <openlog_internal+0xcc>
8c732:       1c43            adds    r3, r0, #1
```

EDIT: I found out why this is happening (see my answer below). If anyone has an explanation as to why the compiler behaves like that please share!!!

Comment: Post the code that the compiler is generating the syscall for.

Comment: In addition to posting the code, you might want to try figuring this out yourself by comparing the assembly that is generated for -O0 vs. -O3. Is there really a syscall being generated?

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the comment. I am running that experiment right now. Why do you think this could be questionable? Also, can you suggest a simple way to do this (I am assuming objdump, but the binaries are 2MB and 5MB).

Comment: @MichaelBurr At the moment I'm not sure where in the code socket is being generated, I'll post the exact location as soon as I find out.

Comment: -O3 is probably inlining something.  If so you can use a pragma on that function to stop it. ... or turn off inlining altogether when you compile that object with -fno-inline ... you may be able to switch it to -finiline-small-functions.

Comment: `openlog_internal` is a syslog helper function (syslog can forward messages to remote log servers if the system is configured to do so). Do you make any syslog calls in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although, one can imagine such an optimization, I haven't heard of such and I really doubt it, because any system call is usually very expensive.

If you are on a *nix system, you can verify it by looking for undefined symbols with [`nm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/nm.html)

```
nm -u file1.o file2.o | grep socket
```

should show somewhere the missing `socket` symbol as

```
        U socket
```

*if* there is somewhere a call to socket.

As I mentioned, I doubt, that there is an optimization inserting any system call and I expect no output from the command line above.

*Update:*

On my system (Ubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6), I found the following note in `man gcc`

> **-O2** Optimize even more.  ...
>   NOTE: In Ubuntu 8.10 and later versions, -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 is set by default,
>   and is activated when -O is set to 2 or higher.  This enables additional compile-
>   time and run-time checks for several libc functions.  To disable, specify either
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE or -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0.

So, maybe through this or a similar mechanism, there is some code included when the optimization is set to `-O2` or `-O3`.

Comment: Hi Olaf. Thanks for your response. Surprisingly this returns nothing...  Does this mean that the socket is being called from a library that I link against?

Comment: As I expected. This means, there is no undefined reference (no call) to `socket`. See also my updated answer. From your comment, I suppose I gave a false impression. Sorry for that.

Comment: So, I found where the branch to syscall happens in the binary (see the updated question). Is it reasonable to assume that the compiler is calling a function that uses socket in one of the shared libs ONLY when I do -O3 and not when I do -O0?

Comment: From the assembly code, I would guess this is some syslog code. Do you call `syslog()` or `openlog()`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... Especially that it only exists in the -O3 version.

Comment: Do you have the same "optimization" when you use `-O2`?

Comment: Thanks for your helpful hints, it turns out that only -O0 avoids this issue (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

After a whole day of debugging, it turns out that arm-cross-gcc compiles **strcpy()** differently under -O0 and -O1,-O2,-O3 when the string you are copying from is a **volatile char***. -O0 compiles using standard user mode assembly, whereas -O1,-O2,-O3 compile it with extra syscalls, such as socket, connect, and send.

So, after all, my initial hunch is justified:

> "The reason that I think the socket might be created is that I am using
>   pthreads and two of my threads are communicating through a volatile
>   char*. So I'm guessing maybe the compiler is trying to implement it in
>   a fancy way when I set the -O3 flag? But I'm not sure if that is a
>   reasonable assumption."

EDIT: Here are some observations to support this claim:

I compiled my code in 4 versions

```
 1. without strcpy() -O0 => obj.o0
 2. with    strcpy() -O0 => obj_strcpy.o0
 3. without strcpy() -O3 => obj.o3
 4. with    strcpy() -O3 => obj_strcpy.o3
```

I ran nm -u on all of the above.

Here are the diffs:

```
$> diff obj.o0 obj_strcpy.o0
$> diff obj.o3 obj_strcpy.o3
>          U __strcpy_chk
$>
```

This means that when you add strcpy() to your code and compile with -O0 no external symbols are added, whereas when you add strcpy() to your code and compile with -O3 `U __strcpy_chk` symbol is added to the object file. I will look into the implementation of `U __strcpy_chk`  on ARM to figure out where the syscalls are coming from. As of right now it seems like `U __strcpy_chk` is doing buffer overflow checks - here is the reference:

http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libc---strcpy-chk-1.html

EDIT: So there are two solutions so far: one proposed by Olaf Dietsche to use another compiler flag in addition to -O3. The other option is to avoid strcpy() altogether and use something as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
{
  cmd[i] = msg[i];
}
```

Comment: This (an optimizer replacing direct memory access with socket communications) seems *highly* unlikely.

Comment: @AndrewMedico as much as I agree with you, when I compile strcpy() with -O0 or -O3 I see the difference in the runtime of my code (-O3 version invokes socket, connect, and send). Also, see edits in my answer. Please let me know if you have a better explanation of this, as I am not fully satisfied with the answer either.

Comment: @TayyarR See my updated answer. This looks like an additional fortify check, which is included with `-O3` in your case. You can disable this by adding `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` to your compiler flags.

Comment: So by putting together your answer with Olaf's answer, the issue is that `-O3` (or `-O2` for that matter) causes `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` to be defined in such a way that calls to `strcpy()` get compiled to calls to `strcpy_chk()` which apparently contains (or results in a call chain that has) a system call to log an error about buffer overflow problems.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes, in a nutshell. In my personal interpretation, the syscalls are there to protect the buffer from overflowing by asking OS for runtime support. Quoting the man page: "run-time checks for several libc functions". In my experience this happens even with -O1, which could be explained by the presence of volatile char* in the strcpy() and pthreads accessing it. I am not really sure about the error logging thing.

Comment: @MichaelBurr `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` is always defined on *some* systems. On my, and @Tayyar's, system the combination of `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` and `-O*` defines `__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL` in /usr/include/features.h, which in turn activates some additional security checks.